# Udev create symlink without defalut mounting point

Tags: mount, udev, symbolic-link

I am able to create a static symlink for my device using udev rules. Hovewer, I cannot prevent udev from automatically creating mounting points.

Here it is, I have a device with  ATTRS{idVendor}=="079b", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0028". 
So, my rule is :

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="079b", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0028", SYMLINK+="ttyACM9"
```

Hovewer, I still have /dev/ttyACM0 when I plug device in.

How I can disable creating /dev/ttyACM0 ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, That's not possible. Kernel always create a node for the corresponding active device only if the device is ignored or removed so no access to it.

Also the node name is enforced by the kernel. udev rules can only set symlink name.